# Textarea placeholder isn't shown in IE 11 being rendered using React

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, reactjs

I have following HTML:

```
<textarea placeholder="Usual textarea placeholder"></textarea>
<div id="react-container"></div>
```

... and following JS:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <textarea placeholder="React textarea placeholder"/>,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

So, I am trying to show the same things using React and using usual HTML.

However, in IE 11 at least, textarea rendered using React behaves like this:

[image]

So, textarea placeholder isn't displayed when page loaded. What's going on here? Both these textareas looks exactly the same in DOM.

Here is a link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bbs8odf9/2/

Comment: Have you created a bug for this? I'm running into the same issue right now. Can confirm it breaks in IE11, but works in IE10 (and other browsers) with React v15.0.2.

Comment: **Update:** I didn't see a report for this among the issues for React, so I created it: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6731

Comment: @arendjr No, I didn't create a bug for it. I thought I will have a time to investigate this bug closely, but I didn't :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it appears the PR that will fix this in React has just been reviewed and accepted: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/6406

I would expect the fix to be released soonish.

Comment: Thank you for you help! When it will be released, I will check it in IE11 and accept you answer after that.

Comment: It's taking a little longer than I'd hoped, but just to keep you in the loop, I just noticed it's merged and is targeted to be released with the next upcoming 15.x release.

Comment: Should be fixed in 15.2.x, btw!

Comment: Yes, it works now! Thanks for you help! New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j94fmxcr/

Comment: Looks like it might be broken. Using 15.4.1 and seeing this exact behavior.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to have regressed :( I saw someone complaining about it here as well: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8546